# Error while overriding action_done() in stock.move

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am overriding the stock.move function action_done(). but i get an error stated below:

```
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

My codes are below:

Original function in stock.move:

```
def action_done(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    context = context or {}
    .....
```

My overriding function:

```
@api.model
def action_done(self):
    super(StockMove, self).action_done()
```

I tried by passing self._cr and self._uid with context=None, but i get error as "Multiple Values for context"
Also, tried to replicate the whole signature as it is, it gives the error " TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence "

Moreover the line which calls the function is in odoo core stock.py as below inside do_transfer function:

```
self.pool.get('stock.move').action_done(cr, uid, todo_move_ids, context=notrack_context)
```

Please Help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an `old_api` call directly. There's a built in decorator for that already:

```
@api.v7
def action_done(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    super(StockMove, self).action_done(cr, uid, ids, context=notrack_content)
```

but you'll have to make sure you're passing in the right ids for the `todo_move_ids` argument

Comment: Thanks danidee, I will try this

Comment: @user280960 if my answer worked for you don't forget to accept it as the correct answer.